# how to print the text including keyword and after keyword from a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to print the text after a specific string.

file.txt

```
I am: "eating", mango
I am: eating a pine apple; and mango
```

I am trying to write a code where it should search for a keyword am: and print the text in "". if there are no "" in a line after am: then I want to print till ;(or simply say 3 words).

output.txt

```
I am: eating
I am: eating a pine apple
```

My work:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open ("output.txt", 'w') as out_fh:
    for line in f:
        str = re.search(r'\bam: "([^"]+)"', line).group()[0]
        if str:
            out_fh.write(str)
        else:
            a = re.compile(r'am:((\w+){3}')
            out_fh.write(a)
```

Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @JvdV Yes, I want to print that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a single regex to fetch the  expected result:

```
rx = re.compile(r'^(I am:\s*)("[^"]*"|[^;]*)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fkwnGJ/2). The regex matches

- `^` - start of a string
- `(I am:` - start of Capturing group 1: `I am:` string
- `\s*)` - 0+ whitespaces, end of capturing group 1
- `("[^"]*"|[^;]*)` - Capturing group 1: a `"` followed with any 0 or more chars other than `"` and then a `"`, or any 0+ chars other than `;`

In you code, use it like this:

```
rx = re.compile(r'\bam:\s*("[^"]*"|[^;]*)')
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open ("output.txt", 'w') as out_fh:
    for line in f:
        m = rx.search(line)
        if m:
            out_fh.write( "{}{}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2).strip('"')) )
```

Note that `.strip('"')` will remove the leading and trailing `"` chars captured with the first alternative in Group 1.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xrKtLD):

```
import re
text = """I am: "eating", mango
I am: eating a pine apple; and mango"""
rx = re.compile(r'^(I am:\s*)("[^"]*"|[^;]*)')
for line in text.splitlines():
    m = rx.search(line)
    if m:
        print("{}{}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2).strip('"')))
```

Output:

```
I am: eating
I am: eating a pine apple
```

Comment: Stribizew I would like to print else case as well in the second format using textfile as input and also I would like to print I am: in the beggining. Any help regarding that would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @user7090 I adjusted the code to return what you need. If you need `else`, use it, I see no need of it in the current scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured it